# RabbitMQ - How to use custom configuration file in docker-compose?

Tags: docker-compose, rabbitmq

I'm a beginner in using rabbitmq and docker-compose.

I cannot figure out how to use my own config file... At start, rabbitmq service keeps exiting with the error:

```
rabbitmq1   | 2022-06-17 14:50:43.578486+00:00 [error] <0.130.0> Failed to load advanced configuration file "/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config": 1: syntax error before:
```

My conf file is the following one (myrabbit.conf)

```
consumer_timeout = 10000
```

The file is in the same directory then the docker-compose file which is:

```
version: "3"
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    container_name: rabbitmq1
    hostname: 'rabbitmq'
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    volumes:
     - ~/.docker-conf/rabbitmq/data/:/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/
     - ./myrabbit.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config #problematic line I guess...
    restart: always
```

Other test:
Instead of this :

```
- ./myrabbit.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
```

When I try this:

```
- myrabbit.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Named volume "myrabbit.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config:rw" is used in service "rabbitmq" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally made it works.

Here is what I did:

1. Create a directory called "rabbitmq" in the same directory than the docker-compose.yml file
2. In that new directory, create the file: rabbitmq.conf (to be confirmed, but it appears that it must be that name).
3. Adapt the docker-compose.yml file as following:

```
version: "3"
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    container_name: rabbitmq
    hostname: 'rabbitmq'
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    volumes:
     - ~/.docker-conf/rabbitmq/data/:/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/
     - ./rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
    restart: always
```

During the boot, you should see:
[image]

Which means that rabbitmq service is well using the custom conf file.

Hope it will help others...